# Rails 4: accepts_nested_attributes_for and mass assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I am trying to reproduce [railscast #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) in Rails 4. However, I'm experiencing some problems.

In my example I try to generate a Phonebook - each Person could have multiple PhoneNumbers

These are important parts of my controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @person = Person.new
        3.times{ @person.phones.build }
    end

    def create
        @person = Person.create(person_params)
        @person.phones.build(params[:person][:phones])

        redirect_to people_path
    end

private

    def person_params
        params.require(:person).permit(:id, :name, phones_attributes: [ :id, :number ])
    end
end
```

and this is my new view

```
<h1>New Person</h1>

<%= form_for :person, url: people_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %> </ br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <%= f.fields_for :phones do |f_num| %>
        <p>
            <%= f_num.label :number %> </ br>
            <%= f_num.text_field :number %>
        </p>
    <% end %>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

needless to say i have `has_many :phones` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :phones` in the my person model and `belongs_to :person` in the phone model.

I have the following issues:

1. Instead of 3 phone-number-fields there is just one in the new form
2. When I submit the form I get an error:

> ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

in the line

```
@person.phones.build(params[:person][:phones])
```

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"l229r46mS3PCi2J1VqZ73ocMP+Ogi/yuYGUCMu7gmMw=",
 "person"=>{"name"=>"the_name",
 "phones"=>{"number"=>"12345"}},
 "commit"=>"Save Person"}
```

In principle I would like to do this whole thing as a form object, but I think if I don't even get it with accepts_nested_attributes, I have no chance to do it as a form object :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get three phones in the view change `form_for :person` to `form_for @person` (you want to use the object you've built here) as follows:

```
<%= form_for @person, url: people_path do |f| %>
```

This should fix the `ForbiddenAttributes` error as well.

And your `create` action could be:

```
def create
    @person = Person.create(person_params)

    redirect_to people_path
end
```

**Update:**

`<%= form_for :person do |f| %>` creates a generic form for the `Person` model and is not aware of the additional details you apply to a specific object (in this case `@person` in your `new` action).  You've attached three `phones` to the `@person` object, and `@person` is not the same as `:person` which is why you didn't see three phone fields in your view.  Please reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for for further details.

Comment: yay! That solved both problems - can't say how glad I am! In the basic rails tutorial they use a hash: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form - can you elaborate the difference?

Comment: @speendo, Please see the update, if you meant the difference between using symbol vs. using object.

Comment: I have a follow up comment.  If the phone model has a phone_type_id, and 
`code`
def new
  @person = Person.new
  ph = Person.phone.build
  ph[:phone_type_id] = 1
  ph2 = Person.phone.build
  ph2[:phone_type_id] = 2
end
`code`
How would the view know the phone type id's and send it back without saving `code`@person`code` at the end of the new method?

Comment: This works very nice, but there's something missing. When for some reason the inputs are invalid and `person` can't be created, following same guides @speendo said, we do `render 'new'` and fields of `phones`(or in my case `emails`) are gone.

Comment: @unmultimedio, you also need to make sure you build any necessary associations before calling `render 'new'`.