# Virtus: Replace accepts_nested_attributes (one-to-many) with a form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, design-patterns, object

Since more than a month I try to get behind the secrets of form objects in Rails 4.

Using [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus), I am already able to build very simple forms. However, I fail to develop a form object that replaces `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (in the model) and `fields_for` (in the form view).

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540679/rails-4-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-mass-assignment) I explain a small phonebook-example: the form provides the possibility to enter a person's name and 3 phone numbers at once (find the whole code [here](https://github.com/speendo/Phonebook3)).

Now I try to do the same with a form object. I get as far as this:

```
# forms/person_form_new.rb
class PersonFormNew
    class PhoneFormNew
        include Virtus

        include ActiveModel::Model

        attr_reader :phone
        attribute :phone_number, String
    end

    include Virtus

    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_reader :person
    attribute :person_name, String

    attribute :phone, PhoneFormNew

    def persisted?
        false
    end

    def save
        if valid?
            persist
            true
        else
            false
        end
    end

private

    def persist
        @person = Person.create(name: person_name)
        @person.phones.build(:phone)
    end
end

# views/people/new.html.erb
<h1>New Person</h1>

<%= form_for @person_form, url: people_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :person_name %> </ br>
        <%= f.text_field :person_name %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.fields_for :phone do |f_pho| %>
            <%= f_pho.label :phone_number %> </ br>
            <%= f_pho.text_field :phone_number %>
        <% end %>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This gives me the error

> undefined method `stringify_keys' for :phone:Symbol

line: `@person.phones.build(:phone)`

I fear however, this is not the only error.

Can you point me the way to realize a one-to-many assignment with a form object (preferable using Virtus)?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create the associated object in a separate function on the form model. I was succussful by doing the following:

```
 def persist!
   @user.save!
   @account.save!
   create_admin_membership
end

def create_admin_membership
  @membership = Membership.create! do |membership|
    membership.user = @user
    membership.account = @account
    membership.admin = true
  end
end
```

You can find an extended explanation here: http://w3facility.org/question/how-to-create-another-object-when-creating-a-devise-user-from-their-registration-form-in-rails/

Comment: I don't use virtus anymore (and even switched to django) so I cannot validate your answer... I would eventually be willing to accept your answer without validation, if you think it is a good one...