# Rails Has many in a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

In my rails app I have the following models

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trainings
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :trainings   #maybe a through relationship here
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

######edited#################

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member  #only member not student nor teacher
end
```

#############################

Now, how can I build the trainings in my student controller

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.trainings.build    #### This is not working
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: where's your `Training` model?

Comment: also, it would help us if you posted the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write accepts_nested_attributes_for in the model and add them in strong parameters if you are using rails 4. Like this :

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :trainings     
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :trainings
end

class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.trainings.build 
  end

  def create
    @student = Student.create(student_params)
    @student.trainings.build(params[:student][:trainings])

    redirect_to student_path
  end

  #For rails 4

  def student_params
     params.require(:student).permit(:id, :name, trainings_attributes: [ :id, :your fields here ])
    end
end
```

Here is a link that will help you:
[Rails 4: accepts_nested_attributes_for and mass assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540679/rails-4-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-mass-assignment)

Comment: Their issue has nothing to do `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, at the moment; rather, they cannot build a scoped instance of `Training`.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. The problem here is i prefer not to have both (student_id and teacher_id) columns on trainig. I prefer only member_id instead. I hope it is clear now

Comment: BTW I have accepts_nested_attributes and using strong params

Answer (score 0):

If you've properly defined your associations, then the code in your `new` controller action will work (I tested it). Check and make sure your `Training` model exists, or that you've used the correct association name (perhaps you meant `:teachers`?).

**app/models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trainings
end
```

**app/models/training.rb**

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

**app/controllers/students_controller.rb**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.trainings.build
  end
end
```

**Update:**

Assuming these are how your associations are defined, you could build a scoped instance of `Training` like so:

**app/models/member.rb**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trainings
end
```

**app/models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :trainings, to: :member
  belongs_to :member
end
```

**app/models/training.rb**

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

**app/controllers/students_controller.rb**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @student = Student.new
    @student.build_member
    @student.trainings.build
  end
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want model training to belong_to model not student. Is that possible?

Comment: can you please clarify? you want `training` to `belong_to` which model?

Comment: Please check it again, I have edited it. I want it to belong to member

Comment: Since `trainings` exists on `member`, you'll need to build a scoped instance of `member` before you can build a `training`. Defining `delegate :trainings, to: :member` on the `Student` model allows you to build a scoped instance of `Training` through `student.trainings.build`.