# Rails create model along with associated data from JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have a RESTful create action in my Rails API for my model `Case`.  It's very simple:

```
@case = Case.new(case_params)

if @case.save
    render json: @case, status: :created, location: @case
else
    render json: @case.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

I am POSTing data to the endpoint (JSON) with the fields for the model as well as associations.  When the form is filled out on the frontend, addresses are included.  The `Case` model has many `Address` models.

So I include the addresses in the JSON as an array of objects, ex:

```
{
  "field_on_case": "value",
  "addresses": [{
    "street_address": "1234 wonderland"
  }, {
    "street_address": "4321 wonderland"
  }]
}
```

When doing this, and POSTing to the API, in the web server I see: `Unpermitted parameters: addresses`

I have this snippet in my `Case` controller in the `case_params` method:

`params.require(:case).permit(:addresses, addresses_attributes: [:id, :type, :street_address, :city, :zip, :state])`

I also have this line in my `Case` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

Comment: did you try removing :addresses from the case params and just using addresses_attributes as it is? This post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540679/rails-4-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

If an attribute is a hash you need to specify this:

```
addresses: [ ]
```

in your params.
I think you can use:

`params.require(:case).permit(addresses: [:type, :street_adress, :city, :zip, :state])`

And then you can remove the nested_attribute from your model as well.