# Simple_form: simple_fields_for not showing the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form-for

I'm trying to create two model in just one form. I have `user` and `unit` model both are associated with has_many :through association.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :units, :through => :user_unit_assocs
  has_many :user_unit_assocs
end
```

unit.rb

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :user_unit_assocs
  has_many :user_unit_assocs
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.units.build
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, units_attributes:[:unitname])
    end
end
```

This is my form, users `new`

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :units do |unit| %>
    <%= unit.input :unitname, required: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.input :name, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I run the code, the form only showing a input-field for `:name` and `:email` and there is no input-field for `units:[:unitname]`. How can I show the input-field in the form? Thanks in advance.

References:

1. [Rails 4: accepts_nested_attributes_for and mass assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540679/rails-4-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-mass-assignment)
2. https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.units.build
end
```

on your controller

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the association in the new action, not the create action.

Comment: thanks. I just can't find where I did wrong in my code. Thanks again.